# General form of the coefficients of the polynomial $p(z)=\binom{q+z}{n}+\binom{q-z}{n}$

Tags: polynomials, binomial-coefficients, stirling-numbers

In my mathematical wanderings I found this polynomial in $z$
$$
p(z)=\binom{q+z}{n}+\binom{q-z}{n}
$$
Now , I'm wondering what the general terms for the coefficients are. First of all its easy to see that  $p(z)=p(-z)$. The parameter $q$ is a rational number and $n \in \mathbb{N}_{0}$ may vary in the interval $0\leq n \leq \lfloor q \rfloor$. If we write this polynomial as $p(z)=a_{n}z^{2n}+\cdots+a_{0}$, the degree only jumps for $n$ even. The general term for $a_{0}$ is
$$
a_{0}=2\binom{q}{n}
$$
My question: what is the general form of the remaining terms?

Thanks.

Comment: The identity you will want to use here is $$\binom{z}{n}=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^{n-k}}{n!}\left[n\atop k\right]z^k$$, where $\left[n\atop k\right]$ is a Stirling cycle number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use *[falling factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials)*  $z^{\underline{n}}=z(z-1)\cdots (z-n+1)$ and the *[Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind)* $\left[n\atop k\right]$ with the identity
\begin{align*}
z^{\underline{n}}=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\left[n\atop k\right]z^k
\end{align*}

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> p(z)&=\binom{q+z}{n}+\binom{q-z}{n}\\
> &=\frac{1}{n!}(q+z)^{\underline{n}}+\frac{1}{n!}(q-z)^{\underline{n}}\\
> &=\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\left[n\atop k\right](q+z)^k
> +\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\left[n\atop k\right](q-z)^k\\
> &=\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\left[n\atop k\right]\left\{(q+z)^k+(q-z)^{k}\right\}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

We use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^j]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^j$ in a series.

> Since $p$ is an even polynomial we consider $[z^{2j}]$ for $0\leq 2j\leq n$ and obtain from (1):
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[z^{2j}]p(z)}&=[z^{2j}]\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\left[n\atop k\right]\left\{(q+z)^k+(q-z)^{k}\right\}\\
> &=\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=2j}^n(-1)^{n-k}\left[n\atop k\right][z^{2j}]\left\{\sum_{l=0}^k\binom{k}{l}z^lq^{k-l}+\sum_{l=0}^k\binom{k}{l}(-z)^lq^{k-l}\right\}\tag{2}\\
> &\color{blue}{=\frac{2}{n!}\sum_{k=2j}^n(-1)^{n-k}\left[n\atop k\right]\binom{k}{2j}q^{k-2j}}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}
>
> We get in accordance with OP's calculation
>   \begin{align*}
> a_0=[z^0]p(z)=\frac{2}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\left[n\atop k\right]q^{k}
> =\frac{2}{n!}q^{\underline{n}}=2\binom{q}{n}.
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and apply the binomial theorem twice.
- In (3) we select the coefficient of $z^{2j}$ accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

$$
a_i=\frac{1}{i!}\frac{\partial^i(p(z))}{\partial z^i} \Big|_{z=0}.
$$
Formulas for derivation of  binomial coefficients you may find [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Binomial/20/02/01/)